# Is it possible to avoid code repetition when an object should return a modified copy of itself?

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently writing some classes that represent symbolic mathematical expressions. All of these are immutable.

However, I found myself often repeating the same kind of structure, so I created an interface to avoid repetition, but find myself unable to avoid duplicating the "substituteInside" method (see below), which returns a copy of the object with components corresponding to "find" replaced with "replace".

This behavior is the same for all instances of this interface.

In my current solution, the interface requires implementing a method `createOp` which returns the modified copy of the object.

```
interface UnarySymbolicOp<InType : Any,
                          OutType : Any,
                          OpType : UnarySymbolicOp<InType,OutType,OpType>> :
        Symbolic<OutType> {

    // Arg may be a complex expression
    val arg: Symbolic<InType>

    fun createOp(mesh: Symbolic<InType>) : OpType

    override val variables
        get() = arg.variables

    override fun <V : Any> substituteInside(find: Symbolic<V>, replace: Symbolic<V>): OpType {
        return createOp(arg.substitute(find, replace))
    }
}
```

The interface can then be implemented as follows: these classes represent the operation of getting some component of an expression.

```
data class GetX(override val arg: Symbolic<Vector3d>) : UnarySymbolicOp<Vector3d, Double, GetX> {
    override fun createOp(mesh: Symbolic<Vector3d>) = GetX(arg)

    override fun eval() = arg.eval().x
}

data class GetY(override val arg: Symbolic<Vector3d>) : UnarySymbolicOp<Vector3d, Double, GetY> {
    override fun createOp(mesh: Symbolic<Vector3d>) = GetY(arg)

    override fun eval() = arg.eval().y
}

data class GetZ(override val arg: Symbolic<Vector3d>) : UnarySymbolicOp<Vector3d, Double, GetZ> {
    override fun createOp(mesh: Symbolic<Vector3d>) = GetZ(arg)

    override fun eval() = arg.eval().z
}
```

This improves things as other methods returning a copy of the object can use that method and thus can live in the interface, but I still have to copy this method everywhere, while it basically always does the same thing.